# FaultException handling in client?

Tags: wcf, exception, faultexception

I'm trying to implement exception handling in a WCF service.
I want this exception to be thrown to the client so it can be logged and handled.

I don't know if the code I've written is right or wrong.
This only gets me "faultexception was unhandled by user code"
How should i solve so i can handle my the exception in client?

Code in WCF-Service:

```
try
{

}
catch (FaultException fex)
{
    throw fex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Code in client:

```
try
{

}
catch (FaultException fex)
{
    Logger.AddExceptionToDb(fex);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.AddExceptionToDb(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply **[FaultContract(YourFaultClass)]**
 attribute to method which will throw fault exceptions.

```
   [OperationContract]
   [FaultContract(typeof(YourFaultClass))]
   void Foo(int par1);
```

How to throw it from service:

```
throw new FaultException<YourFaultClass>(new YourFaultClass());
```

for more help have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949036.aspx

Comment: How exception handling  in Client for **FaultException<YourFaultClass>** ? any sample ?